# Drag cells keeping the reference in incremental order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of a name and a country:

[image]

I'm using concatenation, taking A2 and B2 as an example to output the following text in two rows

`=CONCAT("Her name is ",A2)`

`=CONCAT("Her country is ",B2)`

[image]

Now I'm selecting the concatenation formulas of these two cells and drag them to the bottom so that this can be replicated with the other two names. But since the cocatanated strings of text are in two different cells, it doesn't do that. It jumps a value and doesn't reference the table values in incremental order. Any help would be appreciated.

Current incorrect output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are on ***Microsoft-365*** then try-

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,"Her name is " & A2:A4 & "|Her country is " & B2:B4),,"|")
```

For older version of excels could try-

```
=INDEX({"Her name is ";"Her country is "},MOD(ROW(A2),2)+1) & INDEX($A$2:$B$4,ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A2)/2,0),MOD(ROW(A2),2)+1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works normal in Excel. Copying cells with references are relative to the original value. You move two lines down because your result cells are vertically arranged.
You can

- Place the two cells horizontally.
- Leave a blank row between your data rows. You can hide it if not want to see.
- Can create simple macro.

Answer (score 0):

I looked closer at the textsplit/textjoin solution and that's actually more useful than I first thought. It's easy to even add another row of data, in case this would become relevant in the future